# Export Data From an App and Display It on a Website

Tags: web-services, mobile, web, smartface.io

Beginner here so take it easy. I am building a basic hybrid-platform app using Smartface (a similar platform to Phongap). For purposes of this discussion, the app will do something very basic: you click the start button and it will start counting down from 30 minutes to 0, and when you reach 0 you get 1 star. You can do this multiple times in a day. The more 30-minute sessions you complete, the more stars you get.

What I would like to do is have those stars exported and displayed on a webpage. In other words, I would like the user to browse to that website and see how many stars were collected over a day.

Now what is the easiest way to do this? I have been looking into the Parse platform, and into some of the authentication services out there. I also have a hosting package that includes MySQL and a decent amount of storage/bandwidth.
Without diving into complex discussions of building a backend infrastructure, what is the simplest way to export this very basic data and simply display it on a webpage?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is an object called WebView, you can check it from this document:
http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/controls/webview/

You can directly write the url of the webpage that you want to show.

Here is the sample code:

```
var myWebView = new SMF.UI.WebView({
        top : "5%",
        left : "5%",
        width : "90%",
        height : "70%",
        URL : "http://www.smartface.io/"
    });
Pages.Page1.add(myWebView);
```